# Designing a database for a long questionnaire

Tags: database-design

Hey I was scratching my head for some time over an issue that is bugging me for quite some time now.

Basically I have a very long online questionnaire and I am not quite sure how I should design the mySQL database to store the answers.

So here are my questions:

1. Should I create 1 row per person (the person taking the survey)?
2. There are many parent/child questions(e.g. if answer yes, then
           answer the following, otherwise ignore). What to do with them?
3. For one question, the person can answer more than 1 answer. How to
       handle them?

What I have in mind is creating 1 table with each column being the question. If there is a parent/child question which does not regard the survey-taker it will just be left `blank`. For questions that can have more than one answer, I will create `n` columns (where `n` represents the number of possible answers).

What do you think? Is that appropriate or are there better ways to design the database.

Thanks

Comment: You need to look into relational database design and database normalization. Do not just throw everything into one table or you will have a nightmare on your hands.

Comment: that's a very good candidate for nosql dbs,mapreduce,and functional programming ;)

Comment: For RDBMS what you are doing is called "One Big Spreadsheet" and is considered a bad approach. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFLRc6y_O3s

Answer (score 2):

Each column being the question sounds like a bad idea to me, since it's going to be hard to change / add questions. Changing the DB structure should be done very rarely.

**Table: answers**

For the answers, I would say one table that holds all the answers, with these columns:

- Person id (who answered this specific question)
- Question id (which question was answered in this row)
- Answer (the answer itself, can be string / numeric)

If the person answered more than one answer for the same question, I would put 2 separate rows for the 2 answers. As you can see, there is a single row for every single answer (by a single person). So if we have 10 questions total and 2 persons answered every question once, we would have 20 rows in the table.

If a person did not answer one of the questions, you simply don't have a row for this question+person.

**Table: question_order**

It seems to me that you have another requirement, and that is controlling the flow of the questions - which questions come after which. We will need to hold this flow in another table, with the following columns:

- Question id (the current question)
- Answer condition (string \ numeric, depending on your questions)
- Next question id

In this table you hold all of the connections between questions. If question 1 always leads to question 2, put `[1, NULL, 2]` - in this case NULL symbolizes all possible answers. If question 2 leads to question 3 only if you answer "yes", put `[2, "yes", 3]`. If question 2 leads to question 4 only if you answer "no", put `[2, "no", 4]` and so forth.

**Table: questions**

Another potential table you may find useful is a table for questions, which gives more information about what a question can accept. For example, if you want to know which questions support more than one answer, use these columns:

- Question id (the question we are talking about)
- Supports multiple answers (bool)

In this table you would normally have a row per question.